# Why is atoi giving me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, atoi

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int M, N;

    M = 1;
    N = 1;
    curr = 1;

    if ( argv[1][0] == '-' )
    {
        curr = 2;

        char *a = argv[1][1];
        char *b = argv[1][3];

        M = atoi(a);
        N = atoi(b);
    }

    printf("%d\n%d", M, N);
}
```

So, I pass this program something like this:

```
a.out -1,2
```

and instead of getting expected output

> 1
>   2

I get a segmentation fault. What gives?

Comment: What broken compiler are you using? `char *a = argv[1][1];` should give a compiler **error**. C has no implicit conversions from `int` to pointer types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That compiles?!

char argv*[] is an array of char pointers.

`char *a = argv[1][1]` will

- Get the second char pointer, so now you have a `char *`.
- Get the second element in that pointer, which will be a char.

So now you are assigning a char to a char pointer (which should be a compile error).

I can only assume you meant to say `char *a = &argv[1][1]`. Btw, const-correctness would be nice too, so `const char *a = &argv[1][1]`.

Btw, your code is still very unsafe - you don't even check the size of the string. Imagine what `&argv[1][3]` does if your string only has two characters.

Comment: Without the header file the default assumption is that the function exists (implicit declaration) as called and returns an int. It's a good argument for warnings as errors and high warning settings on your compiler.

Comment: This is not about the function, it's about the assignment of a `char` to a `char *`.

Comment: I'd assumed he meant `char *a = argv[1] + 1;` or `&(argv[1][1]);`

Answer (score 8):

`#include <stdlib.h>` and it should become apparent.

To elaborate: you're passing an integer to a function which expects a pointer, and the compiler could not warn you because you forgot to declare the function with a prototype. This is the cause of the crash.

Moreover, you're simply misusing `atoi`. The `atoi` parses *strings*, not individual characters. If you want the value of a character as a digit, simply subtract `'0'`:

```
M = argv[1][1]-'0';
N = argv[1][3]-'0';
```

In practice you should also check that the character is actually a digit.

**Edit:** I don't recall `char *a = argv[1][1];` being in the original post (maybe early edits don't show up as edits?), but any sane compiler should give a compile-time error on that line. Integers do not implicitly convert to pointers in C. If the compiler does let this get by, then including a prototype for `atoi` will no longer help, since the type error occurred earlier.

Comment: I've seen magical changes to questions myself without them being marked as edited. Spooky.

Answer (score 2):

atoi takes a string, not a character.

Also, atoi is not good in general as it has basically no error reporting.  You should investigate strtol for most cases.